# Application of Derivative - finding equation of normal to parabola

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Derive the equation of the normal to the parabola $y =x^2-6x+6$ perpendicular to the straight line joining the origin to the vertex of the parabola.

Let us find the slope of the parabola by differentiating both sides of equation $ \frac{dy}{dx} = 2x-6$

Let the vertex of the parabola be P $(x_1 ,y_1)$ slope of the line joining point P and origin is $\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$ here $ x_2 = y_2 =0$ being origin. 
therefore slope is $\frac{y_1}{x_1}$

This slope is perpendicular to the given normal ( whose equation is required)

Please guide further.. Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

In general, a parabola can be written in the form $$(y - a)= k(x - b)^2$$

where $(a, b)$ is the vertex of the parabola, and $k$ is some non-zero constant.

$$y =x^2-6x+6 \iff (y - 3) = x^2 - 6x + 9 \iff (y + 3) = (x - 3)^2$$

Hence, you have a parabola whose vertex is $(3, -3)$, which opens up.

Can you use what you know now?

Also, if the slope of a tangent line is $m$, then the slope of the line normal to the tangent line is $\frac{-1}{m}$.

Comment: Therefore the slope of the line joining (3,-3) and origin is -1 and therefore the slope of perpendicular is 1 After simplifying I am getting x = $\frac{7}{2}$ and y = $\frac{-11}{4} $ now equation of the normal is given by $(y-y_1) =m (x-x_1)$ by putting these values we get : 4y-4x+25=0$ but the answer given is $4y-4y+21=0$  Please suggest the error...if any

Comment: Nice explanation and follow up +1

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: You can easily find the vertex of the parabola. In this case the tangent at the vertex will be along the x-axis.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative you got is the value of the slope of the tangent.
Also, the line from origin to vertex is $x+y=0$, whose slope is $-1$.
Since the required normal is perpendicular to the above line, its tangent is parallel to it.

So, $2x-6=-1$, hence $x=5/2$.

Putting this value in parabola, you get $y = -11/4$.

Slope of normal $= 1$, since product of slope of tangent and normal is $-1$.
Equation of line :

$$y + 11/4 = 1(x - 5/2)$$          (from slope-point formula)
So, $$y - x + 11/4 + 5/2 = 0\\\Rightarrow4y - 4x + 21 = 0.$$
Hope this answers you're question.
Good luck!